# How do I get the number of free connections and active connections when using oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource?

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

How do I get the number of free connections, active connections, and perhaps other stats as well when using oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource?

I'm using Oracle JDBC 11.1.0.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [UCPSample.java](https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/blob/main/java/jdbc/ConnectionSamples/UCPSample.java) on Github and it shows how to get the statistics on the connections.  [PoolDataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJUAR/toc.htm) has many methods to display the activeConnections, borrowedConnections etc.,